# Onchange for JQuery Datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Struggling with onchange for JQuery Datetime plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/datetime

I am using the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/charts/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='/charts/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/charts/js/jquery.ui.datetime.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/charts/css/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" />
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/charts/css/jquery.ui.datetime.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#endSelect').datetime({ value: '2011-01-01 13:00', minDate: '2011-01-01 01:00', maxDate: '2011-12-31 12:00'});
    });

    jQuery('#endSelect').change(function() {
        alert("hi");
    });

</script>

</head>
    <body>
        <input id="endSelect" class="grid-3" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I have setup a test site at [here](http://www.thegaiaproject.ca/test.php) where you can test the code yourself.

Comment: Where is that "onChange" code?  In other words, where does it appear in your `<script>` contents?  What happens if you move it inside the same "ready" handler where you set up the ".datetime()" options?

Comment: Where do you define "stuff", have you tried "stuff()"

Comment: I have posted the full code, as well as a test link.

Comment: It appears to be something to do with the .change function and the datetime plugin and .click works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i wrote datetime. it uses the widget factory. events in there arent fired like normal jquery events by design. check out the docs at http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory. there are two ways for you to accomplish what you are trying to do.

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    // you can put any triggerable event in as options on the init
    $('#datetime').datetime({ value: '+1month', change: function(){ 
        alert("hello small world") 
      } 
    });
    // or bind using the plugin name as a prefix on the event
    $('#datetime').datetime({ value: '+1month' }).bind("datetimechange", function(){         
        alert("hello small world") 
      });
    });
</script>
Date:&nbsp;<input id="datetime" />
```

hope that helps. R

Answer (score 2):

I tested this and it seems to be working..

```
jQuery('#endSelect').change(function() {
    alert('duh');
});
```

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work for me. I have posted the full code as well as a test link showing that it doesn't work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Your event binding is happening before the element exists. The selector matches no elements and attached your alert to these 0 elements.

You need the event hookup to occur after the element is in the DOM, all you need to do is move your alert function inside the first jQuery call, this means the code doesn't run until onLoad fires:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#endSelect').datetime({ value: '2011-01-01 13:00', minDate: '2011-01-01 01:00', maxDate: '2011-12-31 12:00'});
        jQuery('#endSelect').change(function() {
            alert("hi");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just tried it, but it still doesn't work. However, the .click function does work so it is something to do with the .change function